# Using chef to set up apt repository

Tags: docker, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am creating a recipe to install docker on Ubuntu 14.

How do I translate the command above to chef?}

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
```

So using apt-repository resource:

```
apt_repository "???" do
  uri ???
  distribution ???
  components ???
  keyserver "hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80"
  key "58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D"
end
```

Answer (score 5):

In contrast to @kaboom, I would recommend the (more modern) [apt](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apt) cookbook maintained by Chef, which also allows to set up repos. The syntax is basically the same.

This is, [how I install Docker](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/site-chefcitypo3org/blob/0b3d95fa8318a95d53ac1d1e336017e9e1eb312d/recipes/_docker.rb#L7-L12) (on Debian):

```rb
apt_repository "docker" do
  uri "https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu"
  distribution "#{node['lsb']['codename']}"
  components ["stable"]
  key "https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg"
end
```

EDIT: This is also available in Chef core without any cookbook as of [12.9](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v129-2016-04-09).

EDIT2: Of course, you can also supply the `keyserver` and `key_id` parameters, if you want to specify it as such.

EDIT3: Correct docker URI and Key as of 2023-05-21

Comment: @coderanger thx, I also thought that this is the case but did not find it listed on [docs.chef.io](https://docs.chef.io/).

Comment: Yeah, the docs are lagging a bit at the moment, half the writing team is out of paternity leave :)

Comment: Totally worth and understandable :-) I filed an [issue](https://github.com/chef/chef-web-docs/issues/105) just to put it on the (visible) TODO list.